# Working out street view heading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-street-view

I was wondering if it is possible to work out a POV heading for street view based on a GPS coordinate?

For instance, say I have the coordinate '43.6653055692 -79.3102166453'

If I plugin the coordinates into the maps API to create interactive street view:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.6653055692, -79.3102166453);
var panoramaOptions = {
    position: myLatlng,
};

var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('street-canvas'), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
```

If finds the closet street view coordinate to the coordinate that I gave, but it doesn't direct the 'camera' towards the coordinate, like the static image API does. I want it to be pointing to the GPS coordinate. This seems to work when doing it for static images, but not for the interactive maps. Is there an option I'm missing?

Static Image URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=43.6653055692,-79.3102166453&size=600x400

Comment: You need to add Point of View (POV) and Heading to  point the streetview panorama in the correct direction. https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/streetview-events

Comment: here is your coordinates and POV=1.5 Heading=65 http://jsfiddle.net/9tnqy0md/ (edit & click to run to adjust)

Comment: @mapperz - Sorry, I should have said, but I know about the POV param, but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically work out what the POV value is suppose to be by relating the street view position to the GPS location.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading` method.

See documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Navigation

Answer (score 1):

The Streetview Images API returns the image from the closest spot to your request. What OP needs is a view from the nearest major street.

The full StreetView API :: StreetViewPanorama class has BEST / CLOSEST params where Google filters for this "front door" intent, rather than just using the nearest image. It would be very nice to access this from the static image API.

In commercial areas it seems like many corner lots are shot from a bad angle, since the side street is closer.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama